# where is loop start in resnet model of tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, resnet

I'm planing to use ResNet to do a classification task, and find tensorflow implementation [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/resnet), howerev, there are something I don't understand as a newbie to tensorflow.

1. How it sample batch examples?
2. I don't see the training loop clause, where is the code called?
3. When will it stop training? There is only the code [bellow](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/resnet/resnet_main.py#L113)

> ```
>   while not mon_sess.should_stop():
>     mon_sess.run(model.train_op)
> ```

how it kowns when to stop training?

I will very appreciate it if there are some explaination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The batching is decided in the [input reading code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/resnet/cifar_input.py#L99). The training loop is the code you pasted (while not should_stop, run train op). It will stop training when the input has been exhausted, according to the same input processing code.

Comment: Thanks for your answering.  I understand this code now :).